# DrRacket On-Key Error/Bug

Tags: racket

I'm doing a project for my Comp-160 class and my on-key function is doing something odd.

```
(define (KEY-PRESS W key)
(cond 
[(key=? key "left") (make-MOVEB 
                     (- 15 (MOVEB-x W))
                     (MOVEB-y W))]

[(key=? key "right") (make-MOVEB
                      (+ 15 (MOVEB-x W))
                      (MOVEB-y W))]))
```

For context my `MOVEB` is a structure which holds a position for a bucket to move left and right along the ground level of my scene. When I run this function it let's me move right with no problems but whenever I go left my bucket disappears or moves all the way back to the starting point.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is probably way too late to matter, but when you say

```
(- 15 (MOVEB-x W))
```

That's like `15 - (MOVEB-x W)`; so if `(MOVEB-x W)` is 100, then this gives you -85, which is probably not what you wanted. You probably wanted `(- (MOVEB-x W) 15)`.